# Extend multiple classes from single helper

Tags: module, helper, third-party-module, extend

I have installed two third-party modules and one local module. I want to rewrite/ extend the `Helper/Data.php` of both third-party modules. Currently, I'm trying to do this from my local module's `Helper/Data.php`.

My question, is it possible to have my single `Helper/Data.php` extend both of the third-party helpers? So far, this is not working. What would be the best approach to this? I know I could fix this by creating another local module to rewrite the other third-party module, but since the functionality is related I'd rather stick to a single local module to accomplish it.

To add some detail, this is my rough setup:

`MyCompany_Module/etc/config.xml`:

```
    <helpers>
        <moduleb>
            <rewrite>
                <data>MyCompany_Module_Helper_Data</data>
            </rewrite>
        </moduleb>
        <modulea>
            <rewrite>
                <data>MyCompany_Module_Helper_Data</data>
            </rewrite>
        </modulea>
    </helpers>
```

and in my module's `MyCompany_Module_Helper_Data`:

```
class MyCompany_Module_Helper_Data extends PartyA_ModuleA_Helper_Data 
{
   ...
}

class MyCompany_Module_Helper_Data extends PartyB_ModuleB_Helper_Data 
{
    ...
}
```

So I am trying to extend two Helpers from a single Helper, is this possible/ an accepted approach? What is the generally accepted approach? Should I split this into a `MyCompany_Module_Helper_Data1` and `MyCompany_Module_Helper_Data2`, or even `MyCompany_Module1_Helper_Data` and `MyCompany_Module2_Helper_Data`

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused, are you actually putting 2 class definitions in the same file?

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried to do. I suppose that is not the possible, since I am trying to define the same class twice right? The fact that I have each extend another Helper doesn't change that. What would be the best approach? Two separate helpers in the same module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not at all possible with magento. Basically what you need is to inherit your class from `HelperA` (of module A) and `HelperB` (of module B).

> In php, you cannot extend a class from two base classes

So if you really need to extend from `HelperA` and `HelperB` at the same time, then the best shot would be..

*Extend your your `Helper` from `HelperA` and then rewrite `HelperA` class in such a way that it extends from `HelperB` instead of default base class `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract`*

**OR**

*Extend your your `Helper` from `HelperB` and then rewrite `HelperB` class in such a way that it extends from `HelperA` instead of default base class `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract`.*

This way your `Helper` will extend from both `HelperA` and `HelperB`. Which method should opt in this case is purely depends upon your application. So choose the right option. Here I am going to show you how to do the first implementation.

File : `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <!-- your module's helper definition -->
            <namespace_module>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Helper_Data</class>
            </namespace_module>

            <!-- this part rewrites helperA class -->
            <helperA_alias_name>
                <rewrite>
                    <data>Namspace_Module_Helper_Rewrite_NamespaceA_ModuleA_Helper_Data</data>
                </rewrite>
            </helperA_alias_name>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

File : `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Helper_Data 
    extends Namspace_Module_Helper_Rewrite_NamespaceA_ModuleA_Helper_Data
{
    //your helper method should come here.
}
```

File : `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Helper/Rewrite/NamespaceA/ModuleA/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php
class Namspace_Module_Helper_Rewrite_NamespaceA_ModuleA_Helper_Data
    extends NamespaceB_ModuleB_Helper_Data
{
    //you need to paste every single method of HelperB here.
}
```

### Explanation

Here `Namespace_Module` stands for your module. `NamespaceA_ModuleA` stands for `MODULE A` and `NamespaceB_ModuleB` stands for `MODULE B`.

Your module's `config.xml` file holds two important definitions. First it defines your modules helper class `Namespace_Module_Helper_Data`. Secondly, it rewrites `HelperA` with a custom class `Namspace_Module_Helper_Rewrite_NamespaceA_ModuleA_Helper_Data`. This way magento will use `Namspace_Module_Helper_Rewrite_NamespaceA_ModuleA_Helper_Data` class when a request for helper class of `MODULE A` get processed.

Now see the class definitions. Firstly, your helper class extends `Namspace_Module_Helper_Rewrite_NamespaceA_ModuleA_Helper_Data`. This means your class is now inheriting `Helper A`. Secondly `Namspace_Module_Helper_Rewrite_NamespaceA_ModuleA_Helper_Data` extends from `HelperB`. Due to this now your helper class inherit from `HelperB` too.

ie ***Your helper class inherits from `HelperA` which then inherits from `HelperB`.***

This is purely theory. I didn't try this before. But it seems really logical for me.

**Note 1 :** Use this approach only in the case, if you really want to define only one class which should extend from two base classes. Otherwise you can go for @Rick Method.

**Note 2 :** For the proper working of your module, you need to make sure two things here. First, your module should load only after `MODULE A` and `MODULE B`. Second, `MODULE B` should load before `MODULE A`. That is the order of loading should be..

```
  MODULE B - first
  MODULE A - second
  YOUR MODULE - third
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the clear and elaborate explanation. Marked yours as the accepted answer because it more literally achieves what I asked for in the question. However, I ended up following @Rick's method.

Answer (score 2):

Your helper re-write XML is structured just fine, but Magento's namespacing convention and class-mapper does not handle multiple classes within a single PHP file. So, a better approach would be to split your classes into separate files, eg:

```
# File: app/code/local/MyCompany/Module/Helper/Partya.php
class MyCompany_Module_Helper_Partya extends PartyA_ModuleA_Helper_Data 

# File: app/code/local/MyCompany/Module/Helper/Partyb.php
class MyCompany_Module_Helper_Partyb extends PartyB_ModuleB_Helper_Data
```

So you'll have to update your re-writes:

```
<helpers>
    <moduleb>
        <rewrite>
            <data>MyCompany_Module_Helper_Partyb</data>
        </rewrite>
    </moduleb>
    <modulea>
        <rewrite>
            <data>MyCompany_Module_Helper_Partya</data>
        </rewrite>
    </modulea>
</helpers>
```

Alan Storm provides a good primer on Magento's class lookup and auto-loading, which may give more insight into why this works:

> http://alanstorm.com/magento_class_abstration_autoload

Comment: Thanks Rick, great answer. I ended up following your approach but marked programmer_rkt as the accepted answer as I feel it gives more explanation for future readers. I also read the blog by Alan and I've seen some of his answers here on other questions. Great information.